# How to return all valid enum values to API client as JSON when using custom validation annotation

Tags: java, annotations

I need to return to API client list of valid `DecisionStates` when the client passes invalid string that cannot be mapped to `DecisionStates` enum.

**Annotataion definition:**

```
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, TYPE_USE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = ValueOfEnumValidator.class)
public @interface ValueOfEnum {
    Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumClass();
    String message() default "must be any of enum {enumClass}: [" + Arrays.toString(enumClass().getEnumConstants()).replaceAll("^.|.$", "")  + "]"; // <-- not compiling
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

**DTO:**

```
@ValueOfEnum(enumClass = DecisionState.class)
String state;
```

**ConstraintValidator implementation:**

```
public class ValueOfEnumValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValueOfEnum, CharSequence> {
   private List<String> acceptedValues;

   @Override
   public void initialize(ValueOfEnum annotation) {
      acceptedValues = Stream.of(annotation.enumClass().getEnumConstants())
              .map(Enum::name)
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isValid(CharSequence value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
      if (value == null) {
         return true;
      }
      return acceptedValues.contains(value.toString());
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry. What's your problem? Are you asking how could you avoid the compiling error? By definition that should be a constant.

Comment: Returning all enum values using annotation